# Coldbox outside root causing same name interceptor collision in two apps

Tags: coldfusion, interceptor, coldbox

I have two applications running concurrent on a server, with coldbox at the same folder level as each of the app root folders

They both call an interceptor named authenticate.cfc but app1's authenticate.cfc has different code than app2's authenticate.cfc

app1 works fine , app2 gives an error as is apparently using app1's authenticate.cfc interceptor

i restart the server, attempt app2, it works fine, then goto app1 and it gives an error , as it is attempting app2's same named interceptor

I have tried no_inheritance, but it did not seem to work...why would this be occuring?

according to the error report, the CF_TEMPLATEPROXY always starts off fine, using the correct path D:\apps\app1\Application.cfc correct

then travels to the coldbox.system.coldbox for UDF and Templateproxy for interceptorstate.cfc

then the last action called is CF_CFPage , which is now referenced to the wrong directory D:\apps\app2\interceptors\authenticate.cfc

Comment: Do the apps have different values for `This.Name` (in Application.cfc) _and_ `Coldbox.AppName` (in config/Coldbox.cfc) ?

Comment: they had separate names, component cache was the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Component cache was the issue, it must be turned off in a setup where coldbox resides at the same level as the app root folders

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coldbox/xARQD93xDNQ

Comment: To be clear, the issue has nothing to do specifically with ColdBox or the location of the files.  You have to turn off component caching any time you have two ColdFusion applications on the same server that use the same component paths between them.

Comment: So it's because the code is simply referring to `interceptors.authenticate` and CF is caching objects based on that value instead of evaluating it in the context of the application? Would an alternative solution be to setup per-app mappings and refer to `app1.interceptors.authenticate` and `app2.interceptors.authenticate`? (with an appropriate `COLDBOX_APP_MAPPING` value)

Comment: @PeterBoughton i attempted exactly that, and still was getting the same issue, although it may have been due to the component cache not being cleared ( i dont have access to the server admin in test environ)